# How do I use scrollTo to always scroll to the last element in a list?

Tags: jquery

So I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Btf77/2/

And I tried variations of `scrollTo` that did not work.

If you were to run that snippet twice - notice that if you call that `scrollTo` snippet after it has been executed the first time, then the second `scrollTo` call will make the ul scroll upwards! Instead of downwards like we want it to be.

To demonstrate this, keep clicking the Scroll button in the fiddle.

Any input as to how I can always scroll to the last element would be great.

Comment: every time I press run the list always scrolls down to the last one

Comment: @Huangism Hey I made a better Fiddle that properly demonstrates the problem. Try repeatedly clicking on Scroll.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the top value changes https://api.jquery.com/position/

For this particular example you can cache the top value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container = $("#todo_container");
    var top = container.find("ul.todos li:last-child:visible").position().top;

    $("#potato").click(function(){
        console.log(top);
        container.find(".todos").animate({
            scrollTop: top
        },700);  
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Btf77/3/

Comment: This won't work in my case, because I plan on adding more elements to the list dynamically.

Comment: well then you need to check the length of the li's in question and compare that length to the length from before, if it is not the same then recalculate the top. Also I did mention "in this particular case"